# spawn in random users in locusto?

Tags: performance-testing, locust

Does anyone know how to spaw in more users in random time using locusto performance tool? Not all users spawn in one go. any option for this in locusto? If not, I am going to switch it to a different tool which support this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are looking for, but you can use `-r` to control the number of locusts spawned per second, or use `--step-load` for more fine grained control

https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/running-locust-in-step-load-mode.html